# Tab completion and automatic Content Assit in Eclipse Juno CDT

Tags: eclipse-cdt, eclipse-juno

I have been using Eclipse CDT for a while now, and the fact of the matter is that, coding can be very slow in the IDE (I use it for the debugger). What I mean by this is, that the auto-pop up (content assist) functionality only works when certain characters are input `[::,->,.]`. In Indigo, you could configure the IDE such that it would pop no matter what you type, without pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>. So, is there a way to bring this back in Juno? A step by step guide would be appreciated.

Secondly, is there a way to get tab completion in Eclipse? What I mean by this is, for example, you have a template (snippet) called `cout`, and it essentially adds something to the output buffer:

```
std::cout << ${"Hello, World"} << std::endl;
```

Thirdly, if the two features above are unavailable in eclipse, and cannot be implemented even by using hacks, is there an IDE that works with MinGW GCC and has the above features (and free).

Answer (score 0):

(I don't know how to post a comment - so I'm writing an "answer"...)

We have given up with Juno because of general performance problems. We turned back to Indigo after two frustrating months trying everything possible to improve speed in Juno.

Eclipse is great and I've been using it for many years now, and normally I welcome the upgrades, but Juno was the only one that has ever caused us such big problems.